A question on the polynomial representation of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$
Irreducible polynomial representations of the group $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ are parametrized by partitions with at most two parts ($\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq 0$) and characters are given by Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda}(x_1, x_2)$ in $2$ variables. Now if I have any arbitrary polynomial representation of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and I want to locate the irreducible constituents of it, can I apply the following algorithm?
First, I will differentiate the representation to get a representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb C)$. Then I will look for the vectors which are killed just by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and each such vector with weight $(\lambda_1,\ \lambda_2)$ will contribute to a Schur polynomial $s_{(\lambda_1 ,\ \lambda_2)}(x_1,x_2)$.
I am asking this question since I have a bit of doubt regarding the fact that I am passing from Lie group to Lie algebra and also $\mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb C)$ is not quite semisimple.
Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

A small but important point is that the partition $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ is not the same thing as a weight. I believe in this case the partition $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ means that it has highest weight $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2$ (as a $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ rep) and that the centre acts by $\det^{\lambda_2}$

@Callum I am just talking about polynomial representations, not rational/algebraic representation. Sorry for the confusion.

I don't think that matters for what I said. Polynomial here just means that $\lambda_2 \geq 0$. See here for example

@Callum Weights are always integral for irreducible reps. So, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are integral, hence partitions.

Indeed they are. But still the weight and the partition are different things. I think there is a sense in which you can define weights directly for $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ (rather than for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$) but even then the weight for a partition $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq 0$ is (I believe) $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2, \lambda_2)$ rather than $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$. It is, as I said, a small point.
